# Rails 4 scope add filtered out record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, scope

I have this scope to show recent posts, but I want outdated sticky posts to be shown as well. That is, the sticky post is created 3 days ago and the first condition is picked that post out, however, I also need the post which has a "sticky: true" boolean value to be included in the :to_show scope.

I tried this, but not working.

```
scope :to_show, -> { where("created_at > ?", Time.now - 1.day).except(sticky: true).order("created_at desc") }
```

Please advise.

Comment: Can you take a look here..http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/except

Comment: You say you also need the post which has a "sticky: true" boolean value, then in code you do `except(sticky: true)`, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to do the following:

1. Include all posts that are 'sticky'
2. Include all posts that have been created in the last day
3. Order those posts from newest to oldest (do you want sticky posts to be ordered first?)

In that case what you really want is an 'or' condition in your where clause.  Something like

```
scope :to_show, -> { where("(sticky = 1) OR (created_at > ?)", Time.now - 1.day).order("created_at desc") }
```

If you want to put the sticky items at the top, then the order clause would change to

```
scope :to_show, -> { where("(sticky = 1) OR (created_at > ?)", Time.now - 1.day).order("sticky desc, created_at desc") }
```